# How to tell if 2x4 is untreated and safe for indoor project?

Tags: lumber

I bought some 2x4s from homedepot. Took a picture of the stamp. How can you tell if it's treated or not?  Is it safe for indoor furniture project?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way: did you buy it INSIDE the store? - then it's not PT - they store that out where it can stay nice and wet.

That's a KD (kiln dried) stud - it's not PT. It's not greenish, as well, which is a somewhat blatant clue.

Comment: thank you so much. Just want to make sure I got it correct. KD means  the wood was held at a high temperature for a certain amount of time to kill any insects hiding inside. Does not involve any chemicals, so its safe to use it for any indoor projects.

Comment: KD (no numbers) means it was dried below 19% moisture when planed. HT means it was heat treated adequately to kill insects (which is normally the case for KD lumber, but the two mean different things)

Comment: @Ecnerwal, "big box" stores in my area store pressure treated lumber indoors with the rest of the lumber.

Comment: Treated lumber isn't necessarily green, so that is *not* a blatant clue. For example, ACQ-B treated lumber will look greenish (unless it has been stained dark brown so it looks more appealing as fence posts or decking), and ACQ-D treated lumber will be a light brown color.